# Channgel Creation Failed. GRPC timeout

Tags: docker, go, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the getting started steps to setup fabric environment on my mac, from the steps mentioned [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) : 
When I'm trying to start my network using the `./network_setup.sh up` script, I'm getting the following grpc timeout error (as shown in the images attached
anyone has any idea what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Contact the support and ask them.

Comment: In my experience, 99% of GRPC code 14 errors with Fabric are because a config is pointing to the wrong location and can't find the endpoint. In this case, it's likely the orderer. Check in your `docker-compose.yml` file, that your orderer is indeed called "orderer0" and that it is definitely running on port 7050

Comment: hey @pete , I did do that. The setup was fine I suppose. Also, tried to work with a new port just in case 7050 was busy, still didn't work. I've added the solution which got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working. The issue was something might have updated the .proto files. I had to run the following command from the fabric directory to generate/update the respective pb.go files.

```
make protos
```